# Send BASIC auth credentials using cxf client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, cxf

I am sending the auth credentials using a cxf webservice client and it says:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
>
> Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response
>   '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with
>   http://localhost:8080/AccountFacadeService/AccountService

My client is:

```
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://webservice.account.com/", "AccountFacadeService");
URL WSDL_LOCATION = http://localhost:8080/AccountFacadeService/AccountService?wsdl;

AccountFacadeService stub = new AccountFacadeService(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE_NAME);
AccountService port = stub.getAccountServicePort(); 

((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "pass");
```

Is there more to headers that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, after many hours of digging into the issue I finally found the answer to my question.

1. Make sure the `role` in the security realm of the glassfish server console is correctly configured and the same is maintained in the `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml`
2. The authentication credentials are passed the way I'm passing in my post. Sometimes when the client is unable to create for you the header you may try password authenticator.

---

```
final String username = "user";
final String password = "pass";
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    username,
                    password.toCharArray());
            }
});
```